# Only 10 connections on my raspberry pi full node

Tags: bitcoin-core, full-node, connection, raspberry-pi

I'd like to know why I only get 10 connections on my full node?
Is there something missing in the conf file?

**$bitcoin-cli -netinfo**

Bitcoin Core v0.21.0.0-7d8a10a6f - 70016/Satoshi:0.21.0/

|  | ipv4 | ipv6 | onion | total | block-relay |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| in | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| out | 7 | 0 | 3 | 10 | 2 |
| total | 7 | 0 | 3 | 10 | 2 |

Local addresses

*myadress*.onion     port   8333    score      4

**my bitcoin.conf file**

#Tor stuff

proxy=127.0.0.1:9050 #outgoing

listen=1 #enable download of new data

bind=127.0.0.1

deamon=1 #to run binary in background s.t. console is free

server=1 #to access deamon API

rest=1 #deamon offers web service so other tools like curl can access it

rpcuser=myuser

rpccallowip=127.0.0.1

rpcbind=127.0.0.1

maxconnections =50

Let me know if you need more info, thx!

Answer (score 2):

> `bind=127.0.0.1`

Binding the p2p port to `localhost` means that it can not accept incoming connections from anywhere other than software on your own machine.

> `listen=1 #enable download of new data`

This allows incoming connections to whatever is configured by `bind`, it doesn't have anything to do with downloading data yourself.

Comment: Ok didn't know that thx! Unfortunately I still don't get more than 10 connections even after deleting the line from the bitcoin.conf file..

Comment: Your node might not be reachable from the internet, if you using a firewall or a NAT. Even if it is reachable, it may take hours or days before other nodes start connecting to you.